# how do I debug a dll in c++ smart device for pda?

Tags: c++

I am new to programming in C++ for smart devices, and I am trying to debug a dll. I did this code to dll from .h file, a simple example, into the code I put a function which does the addition between two numbers and returns the result:

```
#ifndef DllExport
#define DllExport  __declspec(dllexport)
#endif

#ifndef H_SUMA_DOS_NUMEROS_H
#define H_SUMA_DOS_NUMEROS_H
#include <windows.h>
extern  "C"  DllExport float sum( float n1 , float n2 );

#endif
```

This is my code to the cpp file:

```
#include "SumadosNumeros.h"
extern  "C" DllExport float sum( float n1, float n2)
{
return n1+n2;
}
```

This is part of my code for the smart device project which calls the function from my dll:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "prueba5.h"
#include "MainFrm.h"
#include "prueba5Doc.h"
#include "prueba5View.h"
#include "SumadosNumeros.h"


#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


.......................

BOOL Cprueba5App::InitInstance()
{
float i;
i=sum(1.1,2.2); // here it is my call
```

I found a tutorial which indicates that I have to put the path where is the .lib from my dll 
in  Linker-->General-->Additional directories and put the name of my lib in the Linker-->Input-->Additional Dependencies (in my case DLLPrueba.lib).

I build and it shows 0 fails, but when I run the debugger I get the next error message
Unable to start program
%CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES%\PRUEBA5\PRUEBA5.EXE

But if I comment the line where I call the function sum , it debugs without errors. Why? Apologies for my bad English.